# Analyze the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (in)}{2^{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Analyze the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (in)}{2^{n}}$.

$a_n=\frac{1}{2^n}, \quad b_n=\cos(in), \quad \lim(a_{n})=0$ but $\lim(b_{n})$ does not exist. So I think the series diverges. How do I prove it formally?

Comment: $$i=\sqrt{-1}$$??

Comment: If $i$ is supposed to be the imaginary unit, observe $\cos ix=\cosh x.$ And correct the spelling, please, "analyze", there could be misunderstandings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that
$$ \frac{\cos(in)}{2^n} = \frac{\cosh(n)}{2^{n}} = \frac{e^{-n} + e^{n}}{2^{n+1}}.$$
Now $\frac{e^{-n}}{2^{n+1}} \to 0$ and $\frac{e^{n}}{2^{n+1}}$ does not converge to 0 (you may check that $f(x) = \frac{e^x}{2^{x+1}}$ has positive derivative for every $x>0$) and hence $\frac{\cos(in)}{2^n}$ does not converge to 0 and the series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed,

$$\frac{e^{i^2n}+e^{-i^2n}}{2^{n+1}}$$ yields the sum of two geometric series of ratios $\dfrac1{2e}$ and $\dfrac e2$, and the second diverges.